# Which method will be called first ? onKeyEntered (Assume like some data has been returned) or onGeoQueryReady

Tags: firebase, geofire

I am using geo fire in my app ,Assume like I am having some data in my geo firebase and I know , if the given location nearer to any of the stored location data will be retrieved . Assume like I am having some nearest data to give location and I need to which method will be triggered first ? onKeyEntered(This will be called for every key) or onGeoQueryReady ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach a geoquery, you first get the `onKeyEntered` for all keys that fall in the range, and then get `onGeoQueryReady`.

From the documentation:

> **Query Ready**: All current data has been loaded from the server and all initial events have been fired.